# Trying to use ResponsiveSlides on drupal site but getting a console error

Tags: javascript, drupal-7, responsive-slides

I am trying to implement the ResponsiveSlides (http://responsiveslides.com/) to my local drupal instance but anyway I configure the JS code I get a "TypeError: $ is not a function $(function () {" I tried to put the JS code right in the html.tpl.php or as a separate file but it keeps throwing an error, here is the code:

```
// JavaScript Document

$(function () {

  // Slideshow 1
  $("#slider1").responsiveSlides({
    maxwidth: 800,
    speed: 800
  });

  // Slideshow 2
  $("#slider2").responsiveSlides({
    auto: false,
    pager: true,
    speed: 300,
    maxwidth: 540
  });

  // Slideshow 3
  $("#slider3").responsiveSlides({
    manualControls: '#slider3-pager',
    maxwidth: 540
  });

  // Slideshow 4
  $(".slider4").responsiveSlides({
    auto: false,
    pager: false,
    nav: true,
    speed: 500,
    namespace: "callbacks",
    before: function () {
      $('.events').append("<li>before event fired.</li>");
    },
    after: function () {
      $('.events').append("<li>after event fired.</li>");
    }
  });

});
```

So any help on why this is throwing this console error will be most appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

the correct use is this:

```
(function ($) { 
    // code goes here 
})(jQuery)
```

Read this: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.it/2008/12/what-heck-is-function-jquery.html

M.

Comment: So that error went away but now I got one on the speed parameter: TypeError: $(...).responsiveSlides is not a function
 

speed: 800

Comment: Actually even if I comment out maxwidth and speed, it still throws an error on the #slider1 function, and continues down, why is that?